# Error: Operation not permitted

Tags: python, pip, file-permissions, pydot

I'm getting this error when trying to install pydot

```
copying LICENSE -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/.
error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/./LICENSE'
```

If I try to change permissions it says I'm not allowed to do.

Comment: Try running your install command with `sudo`, or as the root user.

Comment: OMG DONT DO WHAT HE JUST SAID ^^^^

Comment: The best thing to do is to run python in a virtual environment. do this `virtualenv env` then `source env/bin/activate` THEN  do your pip `pip instal ..` DONT EVER do sudo for anything python related.

Comment: Its preferable to install python in a standalone inside `/usr/local/bin` or just install `brew` and do `brew install python` then do your `pip install ..` again. DONT mess with the systems python. If you do `which python` and it says `/usr/bin` thats a no go!

Comment: thanks, It solved with BREW